# Is there any difference between "congenial" and "genial"?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms, vocabulary

As the question implies, I'm interested in only the linguistic distinction between the two words I've listed. I've looked up these two words on some online dictionaries. After some searching, I've noticed that *congenial* and *genial* are nearly identical in meaning.

Take Lexico, for example (this online dictionary provides example sentences with the definition entries):

1. [*Congenial*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/congenial):

> **congenial**
> ADJECTIVE:
>
> 1. (of a person) pleasant because of a personality, qualities, or interests that are similar to one's own.
>    ‘*his need for some congenial company*’
>
> 1.1. (of a thing) pleasant or agreeable because suited to one's taste or inclination.
>               ‘*he went back to a climate more congenial to his cold stony soul*’

2. [*Genial*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/genial):

> **genial**
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Friendly and cheerful.
>    ‘*waved to them in genial greeting*’
>
> 1.1. *literary* (especially of air or climate) pleasantly mild and warm.
>               ‘*He felt the students piled behind him surge out of the doors and walk around him hurriedly, as he stopped for a moment to breathe in the genial summer air.*’

No matter which way I try to interpret it, my brain perceives the two words as having the common dictionary definition of "friendly and pleasant". I am trying to see a concrete difference between **congenial** and **genial**. They do not seem so different to me when I examine them that way, but by seeing their usage in a variety of sentences it seems like there is a difference between them.

Comment: I am likely to find somebody *congenial* if they are *genial*, but it is possible that I might find their genial behaviour irritating after a while.

Comment: To me the two definitions seem completely different. Congenial means "similar to me" while genial just means "generally pleasant" - one is relative and the other is absolute.

Comment: What is "a **linguistic** distinction"?

Answer (score 17):

A *genial* person is pleasant and friendly in their behaviour. Because of this, you will probably find them *congenial* [to you].

As you see from the definition you found, *congenial* always has the sense of being appealing or well-suited *to someone in particular.*

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any difference between "congenial" and "genial"?

Yes. The sources below cover the subtle difference(s) between the two words:

From [*The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&pg=PA80&dq=%22congenial%22+%22genial%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-zqSu0-73AhXhp1YBHSy6DWQQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22congenial%22%20%22genial%22&f=false) by Bryan A. Garner:

> **congenial**; **genial**. A subtle difference exists and should be promoted. *Congenial* = (1) having similar tastes; compatible; kindred <*a congenial married couple*>; or (2) to one's liking; suitable; pleasant <*a congenial workplace*>. *Genial* = affable; friendly; cordial . **Thus, *genial* applies to individuals, while *congenial* is generally reserved for persons collectively or for environments**.

From [*Who's Whose?: A no-nonsense guide to easily confused words*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=VppGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&dq=%22congenial%22+%22genial%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiin9uC1-73AhXCBaYKHbwIAtY4ChDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22congenial%22%20%22genial%22&f=false) by Philip Gooden:

> **CONGENIAL or GENIAL**
>
> ---
>
> There's more than a shade of meaning between these two words and the careful user will pick the right one for the right context.
>
> ---
>
> *Congenial* and *genial* both carry the general sense of 'friendly', but *congenial* tends to be applied to surroundings and atmospheres rather than to individuals. It also means 'sympathetic' or 'suitable', as in this example:
>
> *. . . the hour and the place were congenial to supernatural cogitations .. . when I asked him who or what might occupy the tunnels at night . . .* (The Times)
>
> *Genial* is used about people and means 'pleasant', 'cheerful':
>
> *He's a naturally genial man, good company, and will be the host at dinner and in the bar . . .* (Guardian)
>
> Embarrassment rating: 000, since the two words can be swapped around at a pinch. However, it would be wrong to refer to a place as being *genial* to a particular activity.
>
> **How to avoid**: Use *congenial* about place and atmosphere; use *genial* of people.

From [*The Columbia Guide to Standard American English*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=l9g3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&dq=%22congenial%22+%22genial%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-zqSu0-73AhXhp1YBHSy6DWQQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22congenial%22%20%22genial%22&f=false) by Kenneth G. Wilson:

> **congenial**, **genial** (*adjs.*) If you meet someone *genial*, you may find him or her *congenial* too, but usually when used of people *genial* is personal and *congenial* is characteristic of groups and of an individual's relationships to them.

From [*The Facts on File Guide to Good Writing*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Uf-gcunmHfsC&pg=PA248&dq=%22congenial%22+%22genial%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-zqSu0-73AhXhp1YBHSy6DWQQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22congenial%22%20%22genial%22&f=false) by Martin H. Manser:

> **congenial/genial**  *Congenial* and *genial* both mean "pleasant" or "sociable," but there are differences in the way they are used. *Congenial* is generally used in referring to abstract nouns (*congenial surroundings*), whereas *genial* usually refers to people (*a genial stranger, our genial host*).

From [*How to Tell Fate from Destiny: And Other Skillful Word Distinctions*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=VRFxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA138&dq=%22congenial%22+%22genial%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-zqSu0-73AhXhp1YBHSy6DWQQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22congenial%22%20%22genial%22&f=false) by Charles H. Elster:

> **genial, congenial**
>
> *Genial* means "friendly, cordial, cheerful; and suggests an affable, sympathetic, outgoing personality: *a genial disposition; their genial dinner hosts; his genial greeting*. *Congenial* means either "agreeable, pleasant, suited to one's tastes or preferences" (*a congenial climate; their congenial home; a congenial place to work*) or "compatible, well-suited in feeling or taste" (*a congenial couple; congenial conversation; congenial coworkers*).
>
> A *genial* person is always friendly and outgoing, but *congenial* people may find their compatibility in happiness or in misery, which of course loves company. Also, *genial* is usually used of an individual or no more than a few people, while *congenial* may be used of two or more people, of people collectively, or of an environment or setting.

Answer (score 4):

Harry Shaw, *Dictionary of Problem Words and Phrases* (1975) offers this brief discussion of how the two terms differ:

> **congenial, genial.** *Congenial* means "compatible," "allied in spirit, temper, and feeling," "suited to one another": "The players on this team are *congenial*." "At the party you will find a *congenial* atmosphere." *Genial* means "cordial," "cheerful," "sympathetic": "Our host was in a *genial* mood. Genial also means "favorable for growth or comfort": "They enjoyed the *genial* climate of Florida." "A group of *genial* persons is likely to find that they are *congenial* with each other."

I must say that I am far more familiar with the "cordial, cheerful, sympathetic" sense of *genial* than with the "favorable for growth or comfort" sense.

*Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984) is so far from considering the two words close synonyms that it puts them in separate groups of synonyms. *Congenial* appears in a bundle with *consonant*, *consistent*, *compatible*, *congruous*, and *sympathetic*:

> **Consonant, consistent, compatible, congruous, congenial, sympathetic** are comparable when they mean being in agreement with one another or agreeable one to the other. ... **Congenial** is most often used of persons or things that are in such harmony with the taste of a person that they afford him pleasure or delight or satisfaction.{a *congenial* companion} {a pair of not very *congenial* passengers—*Conrad*} {the reticence and understatement of of the method made it specially *congenial* [to the Chinese]—*Binyon*} {[Hobbes's] theory of government is *congenial* to that type of person who is conservative from prudence but revolutionary in his dreams—*T. S. Eliot*} {the ideal of a Greek democracy was vastly *congenial* to his aristocratic temperament—*Parrington*} Occasionally *congenial* is used of things in the sense of wholly and satisfyingly congruous {all such introduced ideas are *congenial* to the subject—*Alexander*} {statement, overstatement, and understatement in letters given a *congenial* context, every one of them is right—*Montague*}

And *genial* appears in a bundle with *gracious*, *cordial*, *affable*, and *sociable*:

> **gracious, cordial, affable, genial, sociable** are used to describe persons or their words or acts who or which are markedly pleasant and easy in social intercourse. ... **Genial** sometimes emphasizes cheerfulness and even joviality. Often, however, it stresses qualities that make for good cheer among companions (a warm human sympathy and a fine sense of humor) {a *genial* host} {he was no fanatic and no ascetic. He was *genial*, social, even convivial—*Goldwin Smith*}

So on the one hand you have *congenial* as a characteristic emphasizing compatibility, and on the other hand you have *genial* as a characteristic emphasizing good cheer. As Shaw suggests the "spirit, temper, and feeling" that congenial people have in common need not be cheerful in the least; it need only be shared. But *genial* is intrinsically about good spirits, a sociable temper, and affable feelings.